# None Payment option not present

Tags: ios-appstore, mac-appstore, apple-id, itunes-store

After creating an Apple ID in another location, I am forced to enter payment information in the iOS, Mac, and iTunes stores.

Even when trying to purchase a Free app, I am forced to enter payment information, and the **None** option is not present.

I am in the US.