# iPhone 4s asking payment details

Tags: ios-appstore

Hello I cannot select the option 'none' as that option is not available. I'm getting really frustrated as I'm trying to download free aps and it will not let me as keeps wanting payment details. I did enter payment details before for one app however I have no money in my account so my card details keeps declining.

How can I set up my appleID to have no payment card associated with it for the App Store?

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125846/unable-to-change-payment-information-to-none-in-ios-appstore and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139633/none-payment-option-not-present and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141276/being-asked-for-credit-card-information-for-updates-on-apps-already-purchased

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are talking about iTunes. If so, Appple support has details on how to configure your account with no associated payment method: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2534